# Автогенерация купонов в Woocommerce + contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, contact-form7

требуется при отправке формы "подписаться" автоматически генерировать купон который прийдет в письме клиенту в качестве бонуса (10%), написал хук + генерацию для Contact form 7, но он не работает, может кто подскажет как это реализовать правильно?

```
//автоматическое создание купона при регистрации на следующую покупку
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_do_something_else');

function creat_coupon_for_new_user($cf7) {

$wpcf = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();

  $coupon_code = 'UNIQUECODE'; // Code
  $amount = '10'; // Amount
  $discount_type = 'fixed_cart'; // Type: fixed_cart, percent, fixed_product, percent_product

  $coupon = array(
    'post_title' => $coupon_code,
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'shop_coupon'
  );

  $new_coupon_id = wp_insert_post($coupon);

  // Add meta
  update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'discount_type', $discount_type);
  update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'coupon_amount', $amount);
  update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'individual_use', 'no');
  update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'product_ids', '');
  update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'exclude_product_ids', '');
  update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'usage_limit', '');
  update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'expiry_date', '');
  update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'apply_before_tax', 'yes');
  update_post_meta($new_coupon_id, 'free_shipping', 'no');


}
```

Comment: "Не работает" - худшее описание проблемы из возможных.

Comment: Согласен) Не создает промокод и не прикрепляет к письму, не могу понять как передать значение промокода к contact form 7  (на отправку письма на почту) после нажатия кнопки "отправить"